# Show an infinite sequence with accumulation points all equal to $L,$ then the limit is equal to $L.$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-writing

I am looking at $2$ statement in my analysis class.
Let  $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real numbers.

> $1.$ If $\{ a_n: n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is infinite and acc$(\{ a_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \})=\{L\}$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} = L$.
>
> $2.$ If $\lim_{n \to \infty} = L$ and $\{ a_n: n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is infinite, then acc$(\{ a_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \})=\{L\}$.

I think I understand what the first statement is saying: if we have an infinite set that has an accumulation point $L$, then the limit as $n\to\infty$ is $L$.

For the $2$nd statement: if the limit as $n\to\infty$ is $L$ for this infinite set, then the accumulation point is $L$.

My question is: are these statements saying the exact same thing? If they aren't equivalent, what would be the difference in proving each of them?

This is my first question here on stack exchange, so I apologize if my formatting or typesetting is poor.

Comment: You have to assume that the sequence  $\{a_n\}$ is bounded, unless you admit the possibility that $L=\infty$ or $L=-\infty.$ By defintion, a number $L$ is an accumulation point if there is a subsequence convergent to $L.$ Equivalently every interval of the form $(L-\delta,L+\delta)$ contains infinitely many terms of the sequence $a_n.$ If you admit $L=\infty,$ then every interval $(N,\infty)$ contains infinitely many terms of the sequence. You treat $L=-\infty$ in a simlar way, by requiring that all intervals $(-\infty, N)$ contain infinitely many terms.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc, If you post this comment as answer, I would be happy to accept it!

Answer (score 1):

For any sequence we know $\limsup_{n\to\infty}{a_n}$ and $\liminf_{n\to\infty}{a_n}$ exist and are exactly

$$\sup_n{\{\text{accumulation points}}\}$$
and
$$\inf_n{\{\text{accumulation points}}\}$$

respectively.  Since it's given that the set of accumulation points is $\{L\}$ then $\limsup_{n\to\infty}{a_n}=\liminf_{n\to\infty}{a_n}=L$ which implies the limit of the sequence exists and is equal to $L$.